# Gridview focusses wrong image in the gallery when i keep on tapping on another image in the gallery

Tags: android, animation, gridview, imageview

I have developed a memory game where i have a gallery of images in Gridview..When i perform click on the first image, via flip animation the image opens up and this continues with the next image as well..when both the images match, i have kept a wobble animation to be performed on the both of the images..I disable my gridview when the wobble animation starts and enable it again when the animation ends..Now in the worst case if the user keeps on tapping on some other image within this time gap (gridview (disable) - gridview(Enable) ), after the gridview gets enabled, it opens up some other image other than the one that needs to open up...

if(firstImage.getId() == secondImage.getId()){

```
                            //increse the point score by 100 

                            level_score = level_score + 100;

                            //disabling gridview for animation to be performed
```

//                              gridView.setEnabled(false);

```
                            secondImage.startAnimation(wobble);
                            firstImage.startAnimation(wobble);
                            wobble.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    secondImage.clearAnimation();
                                    firstImage.clearAnimation();
```

//
                                    }

```
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    //enabling gridview after the animation ends

                                    firstImage.clearAnimation();
                                    secondImage.clearAnimation();
                                    gridView.clearFocus();
                                    gridView.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
```

Please help as this is holding me up to proceed further...Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont think you understand adapter views and view recycling correctly. getId is not the way of getting unique views. use some other data structure added for that particular position

Comment: No,that getId is different....its not from the images in ImageAdapter...i have separate code where i put all the images from the drawable in an array and then display it them when they lcick on the images of an imageAdapter...My point of struggle is wobble animation..Within the time gap when i tap on some other image another image opens up..focus on the grid view is not proper..

Comment: Hmm. You probably need to user animation listener and also disable touch events and item click events for grid view till that animation listener has responded

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=memory.game.brainscratcher&hl=en  Search for Uthra sowrirajan , to download this app in google play